# How to include DESCRIPTION Description in rmarkdown vignette

Tags: r, packaging

It used to be possible to include a magic string in a `Rmd` vignette, and it would pull the Description field from `DESCRIPTION`. This is a nightmare to search because of the reuse of the word. I've searched the source and documentation for knitr, rmarkdown and roxygen2, and can't find it anywhere. I also looked in Hadley Wickham's R packaging book.

I also tried inserting `"DESCRIPTION"` in the vignette text (not R block), but it didn't work.

I remember it being a slightly bizarre syntax, with some punctuation, and the capitalized word DESCRIPTION, but I can't get any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me with a standard knitr block just calling the function displaying it:

````
```{r desc}
packageDescription("rmarkdown")
```
````

You can play tricks with `echo=FALSE` etc pp

And if you really just want the `Description` entry, do

````
```{r descDesc}
packageDescription("rmarkdown")$Description
```
````

Comment: Thanks - I was not aware of that function. I think the clunky "DESCRIPTION" mechanism must have been quietly deprecated.

Comment: "_PACKAGE" was the formula I was looking for, but it is so horrible, I'm going to stick with Dirk's suggestion.

Comment: Correcting myself: the `"_PACKAGE"` applies in roxygen blocks, not vignettes.